# Bootstrap - Format Navbar and Container for Single Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use a bootstrap navbar fixed at the top of my page. I then would like to have a div bellow that that covers the rest of the page. I have the width solved by applying the class container-fluid. However i have adjusted the containers height to 93.5% and set the html overflow to hidden. This works fine with a full screen window. However this solution does not appear o be responsive and fails with window size adjustments. I would like the height of the div container to automatically fill the rest of the page. Code is bellow:

**CSS**

```
    html {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    height:100%;
}

#map-container{
    height:93.5%;
    border-color: black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    margin:5px;

}
.navbar{
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:0px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>quickMap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/quickMap.css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="map-container">
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think overflow: hidden is messing you up.  I changed it to auto and it worked well enough for me.

```
    html {
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Not sure that 93.5% is the exact right number for the height, as, at least on my browser, the div ends up being slightly too tall for the window, but this can be fixed by adjusting the height slightly shorter.  Something more like 91%.